Python join creates new column, putting NaN in index while right join on a common column
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key':[1,2,3], 'values':[11,22,33]}) 

    key values
0   1   11
1   2   22
2   3   33

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key':[1,2,4],'values':[11,222,44]})  

    key values
0   1   11
1   2   222
2   4   44

df12j2 = df1.join(df2,lsuffix='df1',rsuffix='df2',on='key',how='left')
df12j3 = df1.join(df2,lsuffix='df1',rsuffix='df2',on='key',how='right')

df12j2:
  keydf1  valuesdf1   keydf2     valuesdf2
0   1      11         2.0        222.0
1   2      22         4.0        44.0
2   3      33         NaN        NaN

df12j3:
     key    keydf1  valuesdf1   keydf2  valuesdf2
NaN   0    NaN       NaN           1    11
0.0   1    1.0      11.0           2    222
1.0   2    2.0      22.0           4    44

I am expecting to get df12j3 as:
    keydf1  valuesdf1   keydf2  valuesdf2
0      1        11         1    11
1      2        22         2    222
2      NaN      NaN        4    44

How to join df1 and df2 to get this output? Why new column 'key' is getting created and a NaN in index df12j3?

df.join is basically syntactical sugar for pd.merge, ideally used for joins on indices. on='key' will only pick that column from df1; for df2 it picks the index. (With pd.merge this is different.)
Hence, this:
df1.join(df2,lsuffix='df1',rsuffix='df2',on='key',how='right')

is the same as this:
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='key', right_index=True, 
         suffixes=('df1', 'df2'), how='right')

The odd index + "duplication" of key / keydf1 result from the operation trying to preserve df1.index / df1['key'], while actually joining on df2.index.
Instead, you want to merge on key and keep both columns in the result. Try:
out = (
    pd.merge(
        *[df.set_index('key', drop=False) for df in [df1, df2]],
        left_index=True, right_index=True,
        how='right', suffixes=('df1', 'df2')
    ).reset_index(drop=True)
)

Output:
   keydf1  valuesdf1  keydf2  valuesdf2
0     1.0       11.0       1         11
1     2.0       22.0       2        222
2     NaN        NaN       4         44

Here, we set key columns as indices, while also keeping them as columns (df.set_index with drop=False). df.reset_index at end resets the index, as the merge itself will use df2.index.
Or using df.join:
out_join = (df1.set_index('key', drop=False)
            .join(df2.set_index('key', drop=False), how='right', 
                  lsuffix='df1', rsuffix='df2')
            .reset_index(drop=True)
            )

out.equals(out_join)
# True

Perhaps consider a simple merge with indicator=True to get:
out_indicator = (pd.merge(df1, df2, on='key',
                          how='right', suffixes=('df1', 'df2'), 
                          indicator='source')
                 )

Output:
   key  valuesdf1  valuesdf2      source
0    1       11.0         11        both
1    2       22.0        222        both
2    4        NaN         44  right_only # < this `key` only exists in `df2`


Cf. also the answer to Merging 101, under "Different names for key columns", which is more neatly done with the add_suffix method used in the answer here by @mozway.

Nice complete answer ;)

@mozway: thanks, I didn't think of add_suffix. That's a neat trick to keep it short and avoid the index reset.

You need a merge after adding the suffixes yourself with add_suffix to force duplication of the keys:
out = (df1.add_suffix('df1')
          .merge(df2.add_suffix('df2'), how='right',
                 left_on='keydf1', right_on='keydf2')
      )

Variant:
out = pd.merge(df1.add_suffix('df1'), df2.add_suffix('df2'),
               how='right', left_on='keydf1', right_on='keydf2')

Or by passing the keys as Series:
out = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='right', left_on=df1['key'], right_on=df2['key'],
               suffixes=('df1', 'df2')).drop(columns='key_0')

Output:
   keydf1  valuesdf1  keydf2  valuesdf2
0     1.0       11.0       1         11
1     2.0       22.0       2        222
2     NaN        NaN       4         44

